# How to access the point objects in a seaborn.pointplot figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

- I want to extract the y-axis positions of the points in a figure created with `seaborn.pointplot`. I don't need to modify the objects, it's for an automated test.
- For other plots (e.g. barplots) I have been able to extract this from `axes.patches`.
- Have been muddling around in the `axes.collections` but want to know if there's a straightforward way to get the y-axis positions of the points.

  ```
  import random
  import seaborn as sns
  import pandas as pd

  data = pd.DataFrame(
      {"Col1": ["A", "B", "C"]*10,
       "Col2": [random.uniform(1.0, 200.0) for _ in range(30)],
       "Col3": ["X"]*10 + ["Y"]*10 + ["Z"]*10
       }
  )
  params = {
      "x": "Col1",
      "y": "Col2",
      "data": data,
      "hue": "Col3",
      "color": "black",
      "dodge": 0.53333,
      "join": False
  }
  ax = sns.pointplot(**params)
  ```

Comment: Apologies, I will add that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you can loop through `ax.collections`. There will be 3 collections, one for each `hue`. They are of type `PathCollection`. `.get_offsets()` gives their xy positions.

Here is some example code that draws a red circle around the extracted positions.

```py
import random
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({"Col1": ["A", "B", "C"] * 10,
                     "Col2": [random.uniform(1.0, 200.0) for _ in range(30)],
                     "Col3": ["X"] * 10 + ["Y"] * 10 + ["Z"] * 10})
params = {"x": "Col1", "y": "Col2", "data": data, "hue": "Col3", "color": "black", "dodge": 0.53333, "join": False}
ax = sns.pointplot(**params)
for path in ax.collections:
    points = path.get_offsets()
    print(f"hue: {path.get_label()}; y-values: {points[:, 1]}")
all_x_values = [path.get_offsets()[:, 0] for path in ax.collections]
all_y_values = [path.get_offsets()[:, 1] for path in ax.collections]

ax.scatter(x=all_x_values, y=all_y_values, s=200, fc='none', ec='r')
```

[image: sns.pointplot with extracted positions]

```
hue: X; y-values: [126.22035010280258 141.12294652228957 77.11286110373693]
hue: Y; y-values: [99.68997767038964 58.52959793955581 154.63078569762334]
hue: Z; y-values: [90.76316340021354 71.05228738206348 68.13109019572413]
```